# jQuery: Div height set to default height 16px before breakpoint (only happens on Windows browsers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have jQuery on my homepage that sets the height of the FlexSlider based on the height of the window so that the slider is exactly the height of the window, no matter the width. I have a breakpoint at 1025 in the jQuery so that in 1024 and less than 1024 the div #homepage-fold (which includes all the content I want above the fold) and the flexslider images set to the default height of 550px. This works in all browsers I've tested in on my Mac and I can't reproduce the issue on my 13" MacBook Pro Retina **but on multiple windows laptops the script seems to disable at 1041px instead of 1024** *setting the inline css height of the div to style="height:550px"* instead of using a working a script until responsive styles start to kick in at 1024px.

-- I've triple checked all of my media queries and looked in Chrome inspector but it appears the script is setting #homepage-fold height to the default of 550px at 1041< on these certain screens. I can't imagine it's an OS specific issue but for comparison I've used Chrome on both the Mac and Windows 8 and vista machines I've tested on that see the error.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// DOM READY
var $window    = $(window), // cached
    $fold      = $('#homepage-fold'),
    $slider      = $('.flexslider .slides img'),
    breakpoint = 1024,
    defaultHeight = 550,
    resizeTimeout,
    callbackDelay = 0; // ms


function setFold(){
    if( $window.width() < breakpoint ){
        $fold.css('height', defaultHeight );
    }
    else {
        $fold.css('height', $window.height() );
        $slider.css('height', $window.height() );
    }
}

setFold(); // initial setting

// Attach event
$window.on('resize', function(){
    clearTimeout( resizeTimeout );
    resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        setFold();
    }, callbackDelay );
})

});
```

Could someone point out any errors in my code or give me an idea for coming up with fix? I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Nick

Answer (score 0):

You know, I just subtracted 16px from the breakpoint and set it to 1008. I figured this would break the slider between 1008 and 1024 but it doesn't seem to and it fixed the problem on windows so I guess I'm good to go. Still would love to know of a real solution or reason for why this happened -- if someone has one please share. Thanks!

Comment: 16px could be about a typical scrollbar’s width … so maybe the issue is related to that? As for more insight, you should provide a live example – because with just the JS code you have given, we can not possible know how the rest of your CSS might influence the situation.

Comment: Thanks! The site's a client site and I signed an NDA so unfortunately can't provide a live example. But scrollbars are probably the issue. Will look into that further. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To match the width of the window perceived by the `css` and the width perceived by `javascript`, you can add a `div` giving it a width 100% and height 1px, positioning it fixed so that it doesn't affect the regular flow of the rest of the page and then instead of `if( $window.width() < breakpoint )` , you could write `if( $div.width() < breakpoint )` where `$div` refers to the `div` we added above. To hide the `div` from the page you can use a negative `top` style attribute.

You could do a similar thing with the height. But since usually there isn't a horizontal scrollbar, css height and javascript height will be the same.

Hope it helps.